# How access hidden button using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, controls, visibility

i have a link button to remove the selected value in the user control. If we are adding value to the control means i have to make this link button visible. so i am passing the client id of the link button to the user control and saving that id in a hidden control in the User control. and one i select the value in the user control im making the link button visible.

Problem:

If the link button visibility false means unable to access the control.

**var removeUser = document.getElementById(elementRemoveUser.value);** returns null. if the control is visible means it is working fine.

```
 var elementRemoveUser = document.getElementById("<%=hdnRemoveUser.ClientID %>");
        if (elementRemoveUser.value != '') {
            var removeUser = document.getElementById(elementRemoveUser.value);
            if (removeUser != null) {
                removeUser.style.visibility = "visible";
            }
        }
```

Comment: use 'display : none' instead of 'Visible = false'

Comment: Thank Pavankumar. pls make it answer to accept it.

Comment: Use Backbone.js or another related Javascript framework. It will make your life so much easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `style="display:none;` property instead of making the control invisible by `Visible = False`

Using `display:none` hides the element, but the HTML element is still there in the source so you will have access to the control. But, `Visible = False` removes the HTML element altogether.